# How to add a Single Marker inside of an AreaChart populated with multiple DataSets?

Tags: java, android, marker, area, anychart

I'm trying to add a Marker inside of an AreaChart, but I had no success. As the orange dot on this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MR2mK.png

I'm using the sample code provided from AnyChart as follow:

https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/anychart/sample/charts/AreaChartActivity.java

I've tried to change some part of the code too add a marker like this:

```
 DataEntry entry = new DataEntry();
        entry.setValue("test", 10);
        seriesData.add(entry);

        seriesData.add(new CustomDataEntry("Q2 2014", 17.982, 10.941, 9.835, 4.047, 2.841));
        seriesData.add(new CustomDataEntry("Q3 2014", 17.574, 8.659, 6.230, 2.627, 2.242));
        seriesData.add(new CustomDataEntry("Q4 2014", 19.75, 10.35, 6.292, 3.595, 2.136));
        seriesData.add(new CustomDataEntry("Q1 2015", 30.6, 17.2, 16.1, 5.4, 5.2));
        seriesData.add(new CustomDataEntry("Q2 2015", 21.316, 12.204, 16.823, 3.457, 4.210));
        seriesData.add(new CustomDataEntry("Q3 2015", 20.209, 10.342, 13.23, 2.872, 2.959));
        seriesData.add(new CustomDataEntry("Q4 2015", 21.773, 10.577, 12.518, 3.929, 2.704));
        seriesData.add(new CustomDataEntry("Q1 2016", 29.3, 17.9, 18.4, 4.8, 5.4));

        Set set = Set.instantiate();
        set.data(seriesData);

        Mapping seriesTest = set.mapAs("{ x: 'x', value: 'test' }");
        Mapping series1Data = set.mapAs("{ x: 'x', value: 'value' }");
        Mapping series2Data = set.mapAs("{ x: 'x', value: 'value2' }");
        Mapping series3Data = set.mapAs("{ x: 'x', value: 'value3' }");
        Mapping series4Data = set.mapAs("{ x: 'x', value: 'value4' }");
        Mapping series5Data = set.mapAs("{ x: 'x', value: 'value5' }");


        areaChart.marker(seriesTest);
```

The chart is inserting a new axis value in X with 0 value, and positioning a marker on the axis Y at 10 value, as (0, 10). I need to put the marker in any X value like, (15, 20), or (10, 10) and at the same time plot the other seriesData correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured out how to do it. 
The other series must be populated as the same way my Marker is, but then they need to be inserted in a diferent Set.
For example:

```
  Cartesian areaChart = AnyChart.area();
  ...

  List<DataEntry> series1 = new ArrayList<>();
  series1.add(new ValueDataEntry("0.0", 1.0)));
  series1.add(new ValueDataEntry("1.0", 5.0)));  
  series1.add(new ValueDataEntry("2.0", 10.0)));

  Set setSerie = Set.instantiate();
  setSerie.data(series1);
  Mapping mapSerie = setSerie.mapAs("{x: 0, value: 1}");

  areaChart.area(mapSerie);
```

And adding the marker code as follow:

```
 ...
 List<DataEntry> markerData = new ArrayList<>();
 markerData.add(new ValueDataEntry("10.0", 10.0));

 Set setMarker = Set.instantiate();
 setMarker.data(markerData);

 Mapping mapMarker = setMarker.mapAs("{x: 0, value: 1}");

 areaChart.marker(mapMarker)

 ...

 anyChartView.setChart(areaChart); //shows the chart
```

That was a long day trying to accomplished that one.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, the approach you are using is the best practice for this!